# Absolute value of binary number

Tags: binary

I want to represent a binary number's absolute value.

I have `A = 1.101011` which is `-43`, the absolute value is `|A| = 0.010101`

I would like to know how that works and how to get any number absolute value in binary.

The dot is used as sign bit splitter.

Comment: You did not finished your question, am I right? Which programming language you use? Or is it a `pen-and-paper` problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using dot as sign bit indicator? If so, then check [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), you can see how a binary is converted as its negative.

After knowing that, just simply check the sign bit to know whether the input is needed for changing into its negative.